# Is it possible to implement SSO with SAML using ReactJS and .NET 5/.NET Core?

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to implement SSO with SAML in a ReactJS application with .NET 5 as the back end. With [this documentation](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/10/23/how-to-authenticate-with-saml-in-aspnet-core-and-csharp) from Okta I was able to create a SAML authentication in .NET5. But I am not able to figure out how to add ReactJS into this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: SAML is not designated for SPA apps, so you will have hard time. I would say you have to have very deep SAML knowledge and then you will need to code own legacy solution to have hackish implementation.

Comment: @Jan Garaj My client is insisting on using SAML. I am totally stuck and don't know how to implement it on the React side.

Comment: I would say implement auth in the backend and expose APIs for the frontend, which will be used to verify if user is logged. If not frontend initializes IDP initiated SAML login, which will do SAML assertion with backend and then it redirects back to frontend. Whole concept is hacking only for advanced developers.

Comment: @Jan Garaj Ok. We convinced the client to not go with SAML. Instead, we are implementing SSO using open id connect. That feels like the better choice.