# Is it possible to implement Okta SAML using React and .NET 7?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, .net, saml, saml-2.0

I implemented Okta SAML authentication in .NET 7 back end application and it work fine with Razor pages. But can't figure out how to add React application as front end.

When I try to redirecting from front end to server, it's entering in an infinite loop. Here's a snippet of my React code:

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<IApplicationProps> = props => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
    useEffect(() => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const jwtToken = urlParams.get('jwt');

        if (jwtToken) {
            // Store the JWT token in local storage or a secure client-side storage
            // for further use in API calls or authentication checks

            localStorage.setItem('token', jwtToken);
            axiosInterceptorClient.get("/auth/check")
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data !== "") {
                        const { user } = response.data;
                        setEmail(user);
                        setLoading(false);
                    } else {
                        RedirectToLogin();
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error, 'SAML');
                    RedirectToLogin();
                });
        } else {
            RedirectToLogin();
        }
    }, []);

    const RedirectToLogin = () => {
        window.location.replace('https://localhost:5001/auth/login');
    }

    if (loading)
        return <p>loading ...</p>

    return (
        <p>Hello {email}!</p>
    );
}
```

Here's AssertionConsumerService and Check endpoints just in case:

```
[HttpGet("check")]
[Authorize]
public IActionResult CheckUserAuthenticated()
{
   if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
       return Ok(null);
   }

   // User is authenticated
   var user = User.Identity.Name;
   var userClaims = User.Claims;

   // Return user information
   return Ok(new { User = user, Claims = userClaims });
   }

[Route("AssertionConsumerService")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssertionConsumerService()
{
   var binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
   var saml2AuthnResponse = new Saml2AuthnResponse(config);

   binding.ReadSamlResponse(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
   if (saml2AuthnResponse.Status != Saml2StatusCodes.Success)
   {
      throw new AuthenticationException($"SAML Response status: {saml2AuthnResponse.Status}");
    }
    binding.Unbind(Request.ToGenericHttpRequest(), saml2AuthnResponse);
    await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));

    var userClaims = User.Claims;

    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YourSecretKey123456"); 
    // Replace with your secret key
    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
      Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims),
      Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
      Issuer = "Issuer", 
      Audience = "Audience", 
      SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
    };
    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
    var jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    var relayStateQuery = binding.GetRelayStateQuery();
    var returnUrl = relayStateQuery.ContainsKey(relayStateReturnUrl) ? relayStateQuery[relayStateReturnUrl] : Url.Content("~/");
    return Redirect($"{returnUrl}?jwt={jwt}");
}
```

I know it's kinda duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408121/is-it-possible-to-implement-sso-with-saml-using-reactjs-and-net-5-net-core) but want to get an updated answer. Any help would be really appreciated.